# Responsive is not working on mobile, but does work on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page, which should be responsive. I can verify it does 'respond' when [viewed on desktop browser](https://www.dropbox.com/s/or4j9tnlj9g39hm/2013-09-03%2015_23_58-landing.merkaz-shlomot.co.il_blog_landing_page_some-test_.png).

For some reason it [doesn't work on mobile browsers](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4LR9RGbZuuoMUhnMi10Y21WdVU/edit?usp=sharing).

It seems like the `float:none` and `clear:both` is not working on mobile browsers.

How should I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: This doesn't work even on my desk ubuntu 13.04 Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem **and include valid code to reproduce it in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that.
Thanks @meagar...

Comment: @meagar So why didn't you vote to close? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is having multiple bootstrap css files (ver 2.1, ver 3)
Use one version at a time. Try changing blue box classes as below. (As per http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) and your code will work fine.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
    </div>
```